# Manipulate json object using js algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm

I have following json data. What it has is and object that has single property `config` that has single property `cate` which is an `array of objects`. There are currently `4 objects` inside `cate` but it could be several.

```
{
    "config": {
        "cate": [
            {
                "prop1": "val1",
                "color": "green",
                "prop2": [
                    {
                        "prop1": "val1",
                        "prop2": "val2"
                    },
                    {
                        "prop1": "val1",
                        "prop2": "val2"
                    },
                    {
                        "prop1": "val1",
                        "prop2": "val2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "prop1": "val1",
                "color": "red",
                "prop2": [
                    {
                        "display": "Contact One",
                        "name": "Contact"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "Contact Two",
                        "name": "Contact"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "Contact Title",
                        "name": "Title"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Demo",
                "color": "purple",
                "prop2": [
                    {
                        "display": "Demo First Name",
                        "name": "Demo"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "Demo Last Name",
                        "name": "Demo"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "Demo Title",
                        "name": "Title"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "generation",
                "color": "blue",
                "prop2": [
                    {
                        "display": "generation First Name",
                        "name": "generationFname"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "generation Last Name",
                        "name": "generationLname"
                    },
                    {
                        "display": "generation Title",
                        "name": "generationTitle"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "value": [
            {
                "op": [],
                "type": "integer"
            },
            {
                "op": [],
                "type": "email"
            },
            {
                "op": [],
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "op": [],
                "type": "date"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

First object has 3 properties, `prop1, color, and pro2` that are common in all `cate` objects. Notice, `prop2` is also an `array of objects` that contains only 3 objects right now but in real world it could contain thousand or may be more. Now what I want is to place property `color` in `prop2` objects like below:

```
{
    'color': 'green',
    'prop1': 'val1',
    'prop2': 'val2'
}
```

where `prop1` and `prop2` are original properties of this object that is inside `prop2` of `cate` but I added `color` as a new property taken from its parent `object`. The whole result that I want to have is below

```
[
    {
        'color': 'green',
        'prop1': 'val1',
        'prop2': 'val2'
    },
    {
        'color': 'green',
        'prop1': 'val1',
        'prop2': 'val2'
    },
    {
        'color': 'green',
        'prop1': 'val1',
        'prop2': 'val2'
    },
    {
        'color': 'red',
        'display': 'Contact one',
        'name': 'Contact'
    },
    {
        'color': 'red',
        'display': 'Contact two',
        'name': 'Contact'
    },
    {
        'color': 'red',
        'display': 'Contact Title',
        'name': 'Title'
    },
    {
        'color': 'purple',
        'display': 'Demo First Name',
        'name': 'Demo'
    },
    {
        'color': 'purple',
        'display': 'Demo Last Name',
        'name': 'Demo'
    },
    {
        'color': 'purple',
        'display': 'Demo Title',
        'name': 'Title'
    },
    {
        'color': 'blue',
        'display': 'generation First Name',
        'name': 'generationFname'
    },
    {
        'color': 'blue',
        'display': 'generation Last Name',
        'name': 'generationLname'
    },
    {
        'color': 'blue',
        'display': 'generation Title',
        'name': 'generationTitle'
    }
]
```

My current implementation works however, it is not suppose to be done for a large amount of data because it is using a lot resources and memory. **I am looking for an efficient solution.** Below is my solution

```
        var contents = [];

        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data.config.cate, function (key, val) {
                $.each(val.prop2, function (k, v) {
                    v['color'] = val.color;
                    contents.push(v);
                });
            });

            console.log(contents);
        });
```

As you can see I am looping through twice. First I am looping through `cate`(which is not good is there are several lets say 500 objects inside `cate`). Again I am looping through `prop2` inside `cate` loop. `prop2` could have thousands of objects lets say for this example they are 500. So for every outer loop,  inner loop is executed 500 times.

**I am looking for a better solution here that uses less resources and less memory and CPU. How can I make my above solution better?**

Comment: Why are you duplicating data like that? Surely the original JSON is a better defined format? Anyway, first thing to do is to ditch `$.each` - http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/52

Comment: each loop will be replaced later as I already know it is slow as compare to for loops. Right now I am looking for better algorithm.

Comment: The reason I am duplicating data is that I want to send that different version i.e. `contents = []` to a different partial and display it there. One way to do is, which I am doing in current implementation, to re-send the whole json object to that partial is use different loops to display `color` alongside other properties.

Comment: You are asking to generate a list whose size is the sum of the number of `prop2`s inside of the `cate`s.  In your data set there is no way to do that without generating that much data and taking that much time.  There is no magic algorithm that can change this - what you need is a better data structure for your needs.  (Which is undoubtably why the original one did the pulling of default values into the `cate`.)